# Converter tiff to yuv 4:0:0 in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, yuv

I have a tiff file created in matlab , with 16-bit , and I need to pass it to yuv format with 4: 0: 0 ( grayscale ) .

How to do this in ffmpeg ?

Or is there some other way to do so?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is your question about how to use the command line interface, or about using FFmpeg through it's (dynamic/static library's) API?

Answer (score 0):

Using ffmpeg command line, it's

```
ffmpeg -i input.tif -pix_fmt gray output.tif
```

Or, to preserve 16-bit

```
ffmpeg -i input.tif -pix_fmt gray16le output.tif
```

For output to .yuv

```
ffmpeg -i input.tif -pix_fmt gray16le -vframes 1 output.yuv
```

Comment: Hello Mulvya, thank you for the help.

The output is in format .tif, but i need the output in format .yuv.

Its possible use the command of output.yuv?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the TIFF stored as YUV pixels?

Comment: Yes, it is . 

Thank you.